# How to link to specific cells in annother notebook with the new hyperlink UI?

Tags: notebooks, hyperlink, version-12.2

Since updating to Mathematica 12.2, I find that I can no longer create links to cells in another Mathematica notebook.  Formerly, the "Insert Hyperlink" command gave you the chance to select a target notebook and subsequently use a pre-populated list of cell names to target one specific cell.  Currently, only the entire notebook can be targeted.  Is there a way to accomplish specific cell-targeting?

When choosing Hyperlink... from the Insert menu, I see the following:

[image]

In M12.1, it looked like this:

[image]

Thanks so much for adding the screenshots.  You ask my question much more clearly than i did

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Not sure why it was removed from the UI. Can be done programmatically, see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputAndOutputInNotebooks.html#9578).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  While not as convenient as the UI method Hyperlink solves the problem